# Coefficient Comparisons

Tags: r, regression

I estimate two models using the same data:

```
lm(Z ~ X,     data = W)  # Model 1
lm(Z ~ X + Y, data = W)  # Model 2
```

I am trying to test whether the coefficient on X differs across the two models.

In other words,

```
let A = the coefficient on X in Model 1 
B = the coefficient on X in Model 2,
```

I want to test:

```
H0: A = B
```

Any advice on (a) what I would want to use and (b) how to use it in R?

Comment: it's to compare models, not to compare coefficients. imagine, X is something without effect, but Y has effect ...

Answer (score 0):

This would be logically equivalent to testing for the coefficient B being zero in a model that already had an estimate for A, and this in turn would be tested by running an ANOVA for a significant difference between the two models. The R `lm()` function would normally use treatment contrasts and the first variable, X, going from left to right would be added first, so the `summary` results from the second model should useful information.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to know if the coefficient for X predicting Z changes when you estimate the coefficient for Y [predicting Z], then you're testing for collinearity. in other words, your theory is actually:

H: X ~~ Y

So,

```
cor(x, y)
```